# Dar valor a un List<Token> ¿es posible?

Tags: c#

Me arroja este error: Uso de la variable local no asignada `enumerator`

Código que da error:

```
private void offertoro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<JToken> list = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("offerids_offertoro.json")).Children().ToList<JToken>();
  List<JToken>.Enumerator enumerator1;
  try
  {
    enumerator1 = list.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator1.MoveNext())
    {
      JProperty source = (JProperty) enumerator1.Current;
      source.CreateReader();
      IEnumerator<JToken> enumerator2;
      if (Operators.CompareString(source.Name, "offers", false) == 0)
      {
        try
        {
          enumerator2 = source.Values().GetEnumerator();
          while (enumerator2.MoveNext())
            this.TextBox1.Text = this.TextBox1.Text + ((JObject) enumerator2.Current)["oid"].ToString() + "\r\n";
        }
        finally
        {
         // EL ENUMERATOR 2 TAMBIEN ME DA ERROR
          if (enumerator2 != null)
            enumerator2.Dispose();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  finally
  {
     // me da error AQUI <------------------------
    enumerator1.Dispose();
  }
  this.WebBrowser2.Document.Cookie = "1";
  this.c_url = "1";
  this.finallink = "1";
  this.LabelProces.Text = this.LabelProces_OpeningOT;
  this.LabelCompleted.Text = this.LabelCompletedd;
  if (MyProject.Forms.Form4.GroupBoxSpeedAverage.Checked)
    this.CompleteOffer.Interval = 7000;
  else if (MyProject.Forms.Form4.GroupBoxSpeedSlow.Checked)
    this.CompleteOffer.Interval = 9000;
  else if (MyProject.Forms.Form4.GroupBoxSpeedFast.Checked)
    this.CompleteOffer.Interval = 5000;
  this.GetAvailableOffers.Start();
}
```

Otro error muy a menudo, es un nuevo miembro virtual en una clase sellada

```
Código:

internal virtual Label LabelCompanyName
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode] get
    {
        return this._LabelCompanyName;
    }
    [DebuggerNonUserCode, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] set
    {
        this._LabelCompanyName = value;
    }
}
```

Es el get principalmente.

Un ultimo error que obtengo es este:
El nombre de tipo 'RemoveNamespaceAttributesClosure' no existe en el tipo 'InternalXmlHelper'

Codigo:

```
return (IEnumerable) obj.Cast<object>().Select<object, object>(new Func<object, object>(new InternalXmlHelper.RemoveNamespaceAttributesClosure(inScopePrefixes, inScopeNs, attributes).ProcessObject));
```

El `List<token>` no se puede poner nulo, ¿Cómo lo resuelvo?

Comment: Para el "Un miembro virtual en una clase `sealed`", no puedes usar la palabra `virtual` o `abstract` en una clase `sealed`. Luego dices que te da error en otras partes del código, ¿Por qué no detallas el error que te aparece? Y en adición no veo variable llamada `enumerator` en tu código, por lo que no creo que el problema esté allí.

Comment: perdona esque lo actualice de nuevo el problema es que el list token no le puedo poner valor como si el ienumarator enumerator=null entonces creo que por eso me sale el error, en cuanto a la clase que clase debo usar bueno te indicare mas detalladamente la parte que me da error espero tu opinion disculpa la mala calidad con la que me exprese

Comment: no se si haya hecho bien pero converti el List<Jtoken>.enumerator enumerator1 en IEnumerator<JToken> enumerator1=null

Comment: vale lo de sealed lo arregle me sirvio tu explicacion muchas gracias

Comment: Edita la pregunta con la informacion que has escrito así todos entienden mejor tu problema!

Answer (score 1):

Empecemos por arriba...

```
List<JToken>.Enumerator enumerator1;
```

No tiene un valor por defecto, por lo que prueba con lo siguiente:

```
List<JToken>.Enumerator enumerator1 = null;
```

Dado que asignas su valor desde un bloque `try`, el compilador entiende que tu variable realmente no tiene un valor y que está siendo utilizada cuando su instancia es igual a `null`.

Por lo que es lo mismo con:

```
IEnumerator<JToken> enumerator2;
```

Lo defines sin un valor y le asignas dicho valor luego de que entras en el bloque `try`, prueba lo anterior *(Asignar `null` al definirlo).*

El bloque `finally` se ejecuta independientemente de si el bloque `try` falla, prueba a dejar un `catch` vacio *(Personalmente: mala practica)* pero no dispongas de la variable, ya que al finalizar el bucle, el [GC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx) se deshará de ella.

> *Otro error muy a menudo, es un nuevo miembro virtual en una clase sellada*: Para resolver eso, quita la palabra `virtual` o `abstract` que tengas en una clase `sealed`

En adición y para finalizar, te dejo esta version de tu código con las modificaciones que he explicado arriba:

```
private void offertoro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<JToken> list = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("offerids_offertoro.json")).Children().ToList<JToken>();
    List<JToken>.Enumerator enumerator1 = null;
    try
    {
        enumerator1 = list.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator1.MoveNext())
        {
            JProperty source = (JProperty)enumerator1.Current;
            source.CreateReader();
            IEnumerator<JToken> enumerator2 = null;
            if (Operators.CompareString(source.Name, "offers", false) == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    enumerator2 = source.Values().GetEnumerator();
                    while (enumerator2.MoveNext())
                        this.TextBox1.Text = this.TextBox1.Text + ((JObject)enumerator2.Current)["oid"].ToString() + "\r\n";
                }
                catch {}
            }
        }
    }
    catch {}

    this.WebBrowser2.Document.Cookie = "1";
    this.c_url = "1";
    this.finallink = "1";
    this.LabelProces.Text = this.LabelProces_OpeningOT;
    this.LabelCompleted.Text = this.LabelCompletedd;
    if (MyProject.Forms.Form4.GroupBoxSpeedAverage.Checked)
        this.CompleteOffer.Interval = 7000;
    else if (MyProject.Forms.Form4.GroupBoxSpeedSlow.Checked)
        this.CompleteOffer.Interval = 9000;
    else if (MyProject.Forms.Form4.GroupBoxSpeedFast.Checked)
        this.CompleteOffer.Interval = 5000;
    this.GetAvailableOffers.Start();
}
```

**EDIT**:

> Por último: *El nombre de tipo `RemoveNamespaceAttributesClosure` no existe en el tipo 'InternalXmlHelper'*: El detalle del error lo dice claramente, estas llamando creado una instancia de algo que no es un miembro.

Cuando utilizas la palabra clave `new` usualmente se hace referencia a un tipo de dato, como `string`, `object` o `InternalXmlHelper`. Desconozco el parametro que te exige una nueva instancia del xml helper, pero debes cambiar solo ese fragmento de codigo.

Espero te haya ayudado!

Comment: todo me ha ayudado excepto este detalle:        RemoveNamespaceAttributesClosure Creo que debo crear la clase y sus métodos ya que no estan definidos en el programa

Comment: Si te ha ayudado la respuesta, no olvides marcarla. Ya vi la otra pregunta al respecto de tu ultimo problema.

Comment: hombre el error lo quite pero... la utilidad que le doy a esta clase es nula ya que desconozco.

Comment: Esa parte ya no puedo solucionarla, porque pertenece a otra pregunta.